# Scatter plot of data with multiple columns

Tags: python

I have a dataset that has the shape [samples * num_of_features]
num_of_features = 15,000
Is it possible to visualize the data In any way to see if there is any clusters or not. I can cluster them but want to visualize the raw data , something similar to scatter plot.
Is there any way if can be done.?

Comment: You can make a whole lot of pair plots, otherwise it's not quite possible to visualise using all the features. You should just run a simple cluster identification algorithm like kNN and get results that way.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for techniques for [dimensionality reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionality_reduction).

These methods attempt to get the most meaningful data from yours, while representing it in a lower dimension [which in your case has to be plottable] with minimal data loss.

The most popular one is probably [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) [sklearn implementation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html), which is a linear method. I would start with that. Reduce the dimension to `2`, and you can scatter plot like you would any other 2-d data. [Here is a tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/principal-component-analysis-for-dimensionality-reduction-115a3d157bad). I searched for "dimensionality reduction using PCA".

There are many more methods, but it is not clear from your problem statement which is more suitable then others for your needs.